# How to modify Woocommerce's cart's custom values programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to modify Woocommerce's cart's custom values using Ajax. I was trying something like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dgd_update_cart', 'dgd_update_cart_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dgd_update_cart', 'dgd_update_cart_callback' );
function dgd_update_cart_callback() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ '972cb30dd16a544ec9d5142963a81681' ][ 'thwepo_options' ][ 'delivery_or_collect' ][ 'value' ] = 'collect';
    // alternative 2:
    // WC()->cart->cart_contents[ '972cb30dd16a544ec9d5142963a81681' ][ 'thwepo_options' ][ 'delivery_or_collect' ][ 'value' ] = 'collect'; 
    die();
}
```

I need to modify value `thwepo_options` introduced by plugin `WooCommerce Extra Product Options`.

Of course I would not use hardcoded IDs in production, this is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a solution. Here is the code that works for me:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dgd_update_cart', 'dgd_update_cart_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dgd_update_cart', 'dgd_update_cart_callback' );
function dgd_update_cart_callback() {

    $cart = WC()->session->get( 'cart' );

    foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
        $cart[ $key ][ 'thwepo_options' ][ 'delivery_or_collect' ][ 'value' ] = $_POST[ 'delivery_or_collect' ];
    }

    WC()->session->set( 'cart', $cart);
    die();
}
```